# is there a way of creating an ipad app that avoid completely the app store

Tags: ipad, app-store

I am working on an iPad app for a small, general public audcience audience and I want to avoid the AppStore complettely - any ideas how I might do this?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Only devices that have been jail broken, or those that you would use to test apps you're creating would be able to run it.

Answer (score 0):

The three options for distribution are:

- App Store
- Enterprise
- Ad hoc (limited to 100)

The "general public audience" aspect could be the killer for you, so I'll add option four (though I don't think it's a good one):

- Jailbreak

Answer (score 0):

Other than jailbreaking, if you are a business you can join Apples Enterprise Program, which allows business to do in-house app deployment. More details can be found [here](http://www.apple.com/iphone/business/apps/in-house/)